# How to use images inside a select component in Ionic 2

Tags: ionic2, ionic2-select

I am trying to put an image inside a [`Select`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/select/Select/) component in Ionic 2 :
I have put the image source files inside the `www/img` folder in my Ionic 2 project.
However, using a simple `img`-tag does not display any image using this code:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Gaming</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="gaming">
      <ion-option value="nes">
        NES
        <img src="img/myImage.png">
      </ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: custom with list and modal by your-self, good luck

Comment: That could actually work.

Comment: do you mean replace <ion-option> with <ion-list> or remove <ion-select> totally ?

Comment: I have not done anything about this myself, but I would create a custom list (using simple *ngFor in plain Angular2 code) and then popup a dialog with the custom list. I would not use any of the ion-specific html-tags.

Comment: @john now i am facing same issue, are you found the solution?

Comment: Sorry. I have not been working on this anymore.

Comment: @John   I have a same issue, so you have some solution

Comment: @core114 I have abandoned this project a long time ago. So unfortunately, I do not have any solution myself. See my previous comment for some inspiration. if you give the question an upvote, maybe some one else can answer the question?

Comment: @John  Sir, ok got it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ion-select component doesn't allow direct customization to itself and anything that you add to ion-select and ion-option which is not as per the ionic documentation, will be ignore in the generated output.

You cannot add class or style to the component.

One way to do this is to put the ion-select in a parent element like div or ion-row etc. with class and apply the CSS rules using `.parentclass childElement` selector.

To show the images in option check the function below:

```
    prepareImageSelector() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        let buttonElements = document.querySelectorAll('div.alert-radio-group button');
        if (!buttonElements.length) {
            this.prepareImageSelector();
        } else {
            for (let index = 0; index < buttonElements.length; index++) {
                let buttonElement = buttonElements[index];
                let optionLabelElement = buttonElement.querySelector('.alert-radio-label');
                let image = optionLabelElement.innerHTML.trim();
                buttonElement.classList.add('imageselect', 'image_' + image);
                if (image == this.image) {
                    buttonElement.classList.add('imageselected');
                }
            }
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

I have implemented color and image selector using ion-select. Please refer https://github.com/ketanyekale/ionic-color-and-image-selector

You can also check the answer at [Ionic select input of colours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40462933/ionic-select-input-of-colours/50492167#50492167)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am no longer able to test nor validate this method, but if someone else can confirm that the solution works, I will accept this answer.

Comment: That’s fine. Let’s wait until someone else confirms this. I’ve used the solution to one of live projects. If you can check https://github.com/ketanyekale/ionic-color-and-image-selector/blob/master/README.md  ,  I’ve already added the screenshot to the readme file.

Comment: Also, This is tested and live for browser, android and iOS platforms.

Comment: Is it possible to use an image and a label together? As the example in my question, I wanted to display a small image next to a lable.

Comment: Yes, small image next to label is also possible with some CSS tweak. I’ll do it and add it to my git repo with a screenshot.

Comment: Done. Check the recent commits to the git hub repository for https://github.com/ketanyekale/ionic-color-and-image-selector/wiki/images/ion_select_for_image_with_label.PNG

Answer (score 2):

I achieved it like this.

```
<ion-select (click)="loadFlags()" formControlName="pays"  value="select-country">           
    <ion-select-option  value="select-country" >select your country </ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let country of countries" value="{{country.name}}">{{country.name}}</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

And this is my .ts file

```
loadFlags() {
    setTimeout(function(){ 
     let radios=document.getElementsByClassName('alert-radio-label');
     for (let index = 1; index < radios.length; index++) {
        let element = radios[index];
        element.innerHTML=element.innerHTML.concat('<img class="country-image" 
       style="width: 30px;height:16px;" src="'+countries[index-1].flag+'" />');
      }
  }, 1000);
}
```

Timeout is to let the system create alert componens. My Json is an array with elements like {name:"Cameroon",flag:"https://restcountries.eu/data/cmr.svg"}

[image: this is my result]

Answer (score 0):

On your basis, I have worked out a more concise solution！

The method 'prepareImageSelector' is used as the Click event of the control。

Thank you！

```js
   image: string = 'English';
 
   prepareImageSelector() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let buttonElements = document.querySelectorAll('div.alert-radio-group button');
      if (!buttonElements.length) {
        this.prepareImageSelector();
      } else {
        for (let index = 0; index < buttonElements.length; index++) {
          let buttonElement = buttonElements[index];
          let optionLabelElement = buttonElement.querySelector('.alert-radio-label');
          let image = optionLabelElement.innerHTML.trim();
          if (image == this.image) {
            optionLabelElement.innerHTML += '<img  src="assets/img/English.png" style="width:20px;height:20px;float:right;"/>';
          }
        }
      }
    }, 100);
  }
```

Comment: When I run your code snippet I get _"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"_.

Comment: No, you shouldn't. You should add it to your JS / TS code and try it! In the process of trying, we should pay attention to these problems:
 1.The cartridge frame must be ‘AlertController’
 2.Path Problem of Pictures

Comment: OK, but in that case what is the point of providing a **Run code snippet** button at all? Why not just provide your code and explain how it should be implemented? Providing your solution as runnable code that doesn't work seems counterproductive. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

There are already some great answers, and I honestly think Select with some images should have been part of the core Ionic library, but here we are.

I made the following adaptations for my answer:

- Implemented with Ionic Vue (Ionic 6, so it's still an issue)
- Flags for the countries are nested in a country JSON obtained from an API call.
- Implemented for Action Sheet instead of Alert as the other answers
- Flags appear on the left instead of the right

First, the HTML:

```html
<IonSelect @click="loadFlags()" placeholder="Country" :interface-options="customAlertOptions" interface="action-sheet" cancelText="Cancel" style="width: 100%" v-model="selected_country">
  <template v-for="(country, index) in countries" :key="index">
    <div class="ion-text-center">
      <IonSelectOption :value="country.code">
        <IonLabel>{{ country.name }}</IonLabel>
      </IonSelectOption>
    </div>
  </template>
</IonSelect>
```

And then the Javascript:

```js
loadFlags() {
  let that = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    let radios = document.getElementsByClassName('action-sheet-button-inner');
    for (let i = 0; i < that.countries.length; i++) {
      let element = radios[i];
      element.innerHTML = `<div style="display: flex; position: relative; width: 100%"><img style="width: 40px;height:40px;" src="${that.countries[i].flag}"/>`
          + `<span style="font-size:16px; position: absolute; top:10px; left: 70px;">${element.innerHTML}</span></div>`
     }
  }, 10)
}
```

Even though it's a little crude, the innerHTML in the `loadFlags` function, with some HTML and CSS, can be used to achieve almost anything.