# Ionic select input of colours

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to add a select input of colours. The colours that I want to add as options are the following: http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#header
How can I write the select so that when the user selects a colour, he sees the option as the colour and not as the name of colour?

This is what I have now, it is acceptable when running in browser but when I run from phone, the background colour is not visible and the user only sees the name of the colour:

> ```
>    <select ng-model="category.colour" required>
>                     <option selected style="background-color: white" class="light">light</option>
>                     <option style="background-color: cornsilk" class="stable">stable</option>
>                     <option style="background-color: DodgerBlue " class="positive">positive</option>
>                     <option style="background-color: aqua" class="calm">calm</option>
>                     <option style="background-color: YellowGreen" class="balanced">balanced</option>
>                     <option style="background-color: Gold" class="energized">energized</option>
>                     <option style="background-color: Crimson " class="assertive">assertive</option>
>                     <option style="background-color: BlueViolet " class="royal">royal</option>
>                     <option style="background-color: black" class="dark">dark</option>
>                 </select>
> ```

Comment: Can you post code with what have you tried?

Comment: @Ionut I have updated with what I have now

Comment: Ok. Tested your code. So you're not actually using Ionic framework to change colors, you are using plain CSS. On mobile devices you can't do anything to style those options from select. You have to make your own select using other HTML elements. I don't see another way. Also, it seems kind of ugly to have your dropdown options in multiple colors like that.

Comment: this may helps u check it http://jsfiddle.net/sai525/xt3xv/370/

Comment: @SaEChowdary, your code won't help. Will not work on mobile devices. Every device has their own way of styling selects.

Comment: @Ionut what exactly do you recommend? What different elements should I use for this?

Comment: @SaEChowdary Ionut is right. That does not help me. It's exactly what I have now. The colours won't appear on mobile devices because the device changes how the select appears on the screen.

Comment: You can use divs, list elements, etc. And then use JavaScript to make it act lilke a select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented color and image selector with the latest version of ionic and using ion-select.

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can read a brief explanation at 
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-select-list-option-with-flag-image/90972/10

The git repository is: https://github.com/ketanyekale/ionic-color-and-image-selector