# Add image to ion-select-option (ion-select)

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, sass

How I can add image to ion-option in ion-select?
I wanna use it for select language with country icon

```
   <ion-select interface="popover" [interfaceOptions]="opts"
                        slot="end">
                <ion-select-option 
                    *ngFor="let item of (langs$ | async)" 
                    [value]="item.name" class="lang-item">
                    {{item.name}}
                </ion-select-option>
            </ion-select>


// .ts


    opts: any = {
        cssClass: 'lang'
    };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use images inside a select component in Ionic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37694564/how-to-use-images-inside-a-select-component-in-ionic-2)

Comment: I saw it, but  it look terrible. And now Ionic 5.